# Merging List Arrays

Tags: array, vba

Some utility functions I re-wrote today:

**Purpose:**

> - Given an arbitrary list of 1-D arrays (possibly empty variables), return a
>     1-D array containing unique values from all lists.
> - Ex: Given (1,2,3) (1,2,4), (4,7,9) and Empty, return (1,2,3,4,7,9)
> - The returned list will not necessarily be sorted

---

**Notes on debugging:**

The target environment for this code is non-critical macros running on either my computer or computers within about 20 feet of my desk. So:

```
Debug.Print "message"
Stop
```

Is my preferred way of dealing with unexpected errors for the time being.

---

**Desired Feedback:**

Particularly looking for feedback on readability, understandability, and documentation.

---

### `MergeLists()`

```
Public Function MergeLists(ParamArray inputLists()) As Variant
    '/ Given an arbitrary list of 1-D arrays (possibly empty variables), return a 1-D array containing unique values from all lists.
    '/ Ex: Given (1,2,3) (1,2,4), (4,7,9) and Empty, return (1,2,3,4,7,9)
    '/ The returned list will not necessarily be sorted

    Dim LB1 As Long, UB1 As Long
    LB1 = LBound(inputLists)
    UB1 = UBound(inputLists)

    '/ Validate inputs as either 1-D arrays, or empty
    Dim isValidArgument As Boolean
    isValidArgument = True
    Dim ix As Long
    For ix = LB1 To UB1
        If Not IsValidArray(inputLists(ix), 1, allowEmpty:=True) Then
            Debug.Print "Invalid argument. ix = " & ix
            isValidArgument = False
        End If
    Next ix

    If Not isValidArgument Then
        Debug.Print "one or more arguments are invalid"
        Stop
    End If

    '/ For each list, add values as key-values to a central dictionary
    Dim valuesDict As Dictionary
    Set valuesDict = New Dictionary
    Dim iy As Long
    For ix = LB1 To UB1
        Dim currentArray As Variant
        currentArray = inputLists(ix)
        If Not IsEmpty(currentArray) Then
            For iy = LBound(currentArray) To UBound(currentArray)
                valuesDict.item(currentArray(iy)) = currentArray(iy)
            Next iy
        End If
    Next ix

    '/ Read out all key-values (already unique) to a new array
    Dim mergedArray As Variant
    ReDim mergedArray(1 To 1)
    Dim valueCounter As Long
    valueCounter = 0
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In valuesDict.Keys()
        valueCounter = valueCounter + 1
        ReDim Preserve mergedArray(1 To valueCounter)
        mergedArray(valueCounter) = valuesDict.item(key)
    Next key

    MergeLists = mergedArray

End Function
```

---

**`IsValidArray()`**

```
Public Function IsValidArray(ByRef targetArray As Variant, ByVal validNumberOfDimensions As Long, Optional ByVal allowEmpty As Boolean) As Boolean
    '/ Check whether the target is an allocated array with the specified number of dimensions

    If allowEmpty And IsEmpty(targetArray) Then
        IsValidArray = True
    Else
        IsValidArray = (IsAllocated(targetArray) And (DimensionCountOfArray(targetArray) = validNumberOfDimensions))
    End If

End Function
```

---

**`IsAllocated()`**

```
Public Function IsAllocated(ByRef varArray As Variant) As Boolean
    '/ Given a Variant:
    '/ Check that it is an array
    '/ Check that it has assigned Bounds in at least the first dimension

    On Error GoTo CleanFail:
    IsAllocated = IsArray(varArray) And Not IsError(LBound(varArray, 1)) And LBound(varArray, 1) <= UBound(varArray, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

CleanExit:
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsAllocated = False
    Resume CleanExit

End Function
```

---

**`DimensionCountOfArray()`**

```
Public Function DimensionCountOfArray(ByRef targetArray As Variant)
    '/ First check that the Variable is, in fact, an allocated array
    '/ If it is, iteratively attempt to access dimensions until an error is encountered, then return the last dimension successfully accessed
    '/ If it is not an allocated array, return 0

    Dim maxDimension As Long
    maxDimension = 0

    If Not IsAllocated(targetArray) Then
        '/ Not a valid target, return 0
        GoTo maxFound
    Else
        '/ Is a valid target, check dimensions
        Dim errCheck As Variant
        Do While maxDimension <= 100000 '/ Arbitrary Magic Number
            On Error GoTo maxFound
                errCheck = LBound(targetArray, maxDimension + 1)
            On Error GoTo 0
            maxDimension = maxDimension + 1
        Loop
    End If

maxFound:
    On Error GoTo 0
    DimensionCountOfArray = maxDimension

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

> `Dim valuesDict As Dictionary`

You don't use extra functionality of `Dictionary`, why not use a `Collection`?

> `If allowEmpty And IsEmpty(targetArray) Then`

This will fail if `allowEmpty` is `Missing`

Comment: Habit I guess. I can't remember the last time I needed to use a collection.